# Using a script to edit data from a form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

It appears the data submitted to a Google Form is saved not just in the associated spreadsheet, but also in the Form itself  I have an HTML interface that displays the data to internal staff in a Non-Profits account.  Some of this data may change or may not be known at the time of submission. Other information is saved in additional fields in the associated spreadsheet. I can add and edit that data, but is it possible to edit the data in the form file as well?

Comment: I don't think there is no way that we can edit the data stored in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the data saved as a response in the form itself, and you can submit new responses programmatically.  I don't think you can alter existing responses with Google Apps Script.  See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
```